# How can I take as input, the output from another c file?

Tags: c

So for example, let say I have a file server.c which is not printing anything but has a string e.g: "Fish is swimming in the air". What I want to do is to let child.c to print the string of server.c
Is that even possible? I was told that using pipelines (such popen()) would help. But I can't find what I want out there.

Comment: I think you mean "how can I take the output of another program as input for mine?" if not, then I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for, but if you're trying to pipe the output from one program into another, why not use a [pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29) , in the same way you would when piping data on the commandline, e.g. `ls -la | more`.

Comment: @AlejandroDiaz yeah, that's what I mean! Aha, sorry, my brain goes crazy from reading a lot of articles about C.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie thanks for the suggestion! I wonder if I could use function popen() instead of piping through the commandline? Is that possible?

Comment: It might be operating system specific. Linux has [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there is possibly a way to do that using pipe functions (check something like this site unixwiz.net/techtips/remap-pip-fds.html) but what you are describing sounds like another client connecting to the server and having the strings sent to it across a socket. Using a socket would also open up the ability to check the server string over a network. Typically with error/extra log checking with a server it is either handled by the server opening a log file or by sending it across a socket. You could determine to send it to a specific client that uses PSK over a TLS connection if security is an issue.

For TLS examples check out https://github.com/wolfSSL/wolfssl-examples

Added in code for piping

receiver.c

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <stdlib.h>
  3 #include <unistd.h>
  4 
  5 int main() {
  6 
  7     char buffer[1024];
  8 
  9     fscanf(stdin, "%s", buffer);
 10 
 11     printf("receiver got data and is printing it\n");
 12     printf("%s\n", buffer);
 13 
 14     return 0;
 15 }
```

sender.c

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <stdlib.h>
  3 #include <unistd.h>
  4 
  5 
  6 int main()
  7 {
  8     FILE *output;
  9 
 10     output = popen ("./receiver","w");
 11     if (!output) {
 12         /* error checking opening pipe */
 13         fprintf(stderr, "could not open pipe\n");
 14         return 1;
 15     }
 16 
 17     fprintf(output, "%s", "hello_world\n");
 18 
 19     if (pclose (output) != 0) {
 20         /* error checking on closing pipe */
 21         fprintf(stderr, " could not run receiver\n");
 22         return 1;
 23     }
 24 
 25     return 0;
 26 }
```

compile and run in the same directory using

```
gcc sender.c -o sender
gcc receiver.c -o receiver
./sender
```

Comment: Wow this sounds complicated. But you're right, a client will be connected to server to get the string from server and print it. I wonder if I could use pipelining instead of doing it over a TLS connection?
And if I do want to do it over a TLS connection, do you have any suggested references? Thanks before!

Comment: Hi Ultimate Tc, edited the answer, hope it helps. I still recommend using TLS (if concerned about security) or at the least a plain TCP connection and sending the strings across a socket.

Comment: If concerned about security, the first thing to get rid of is the buffer overflow vulnerability on line 9 of `receiver.c`.

Comment: alr, thanks guys! I will do my research now!